# Show weather based on users location

Tags: php, wordpress, location, weather

I am using a code that changes my wordpress website's background according to the Yahoo API URL I inserted. Is there anyway to make it automatically show the Visitors weather without any databases? I have though of using Google's API but I am a novice in programming and dont know how to implement it into my website. Please help!
The code can be viewed here: http://css-tricks.com/using-weather-data-to-change-your-websites-apperance-through-php-and-css/

Please be thorough because I am new to PHP
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will get a user's zip code from their IP address using the open-source [IP2Coordinates service](http://www.datasciencetoolkit.org/developerdocs#ip2coordinates) from the [Data Science Toolkit](http://www.datasciencetoolkit.org/).

There are more accurate Geo-location APIs out there, but this one is absolutely free and dead simple to use. If I were developing this on a production site, I'd use [HTML5 Geolocation](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_geolocation.asp) as my primary method with a fallback to a better IP geolocator, like [Max Mind](http://www.maxmind.com/app/ip-location).

Note that this will only work for US users of your site. You should probably pass more detailed data to one of the other Yahoo place APIs to get one of their WOEIDs to use (or pick a different weather API).

Here is the code for you. Put this right after the `<?php` tag in your sample code. Once you're sure it's working, comment out all the lines that begin with `print`.

```
//Get the user's IP address
$user_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
//The Data Science Toolkit URL
$url = 'http://www.datasciencetoolkit.org/ip2coordinates/';
//Find the user's location from their IP. 
//*** You need the get_data function from the sample code
$raw_geocode = json_decode( get_data( $url . $user_ip) );
//Check if the user is in the US
if ('US' === $raw_geocode->$user_ip->country_code) {
  //If yes, store their zip code in a variable, and print it
  $zip_code = $raw_geocode->$user_ip->postal_code;
  printf('<p>Your zip code is: %s</p>', $raw_geocode->$user_ip->postal_code);
} else {
  //If the user isn't in the US, set a sip code that will work.
  $zip_code = '97211';
  //and print an error
  printf('<p>Sorry, this app does not work in %s.</p>', $raw_geocode->$user_ip->country_name);
}

//Print the raw data for debugging.
printf('<pre>%s</pre>', print_r($raw_geocode, true));
```

Now change the line in the sample code that begins with `$data =` to this:

```
$data = get_data("http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?p={$zip_code}&u=f");
```

Comment: What do I need to replace to get this code to work ( or does it work right out of the box)? Sorry I don't have access to a comp until tomorrow.  thanks so much for the code and you should post this to CSS tricks or something; I think this is one of the only tutorials out there that can do this!

Comment: It works perfectly!!! All I had to do was delete the parts where it printed text (it messed up my wp theme) and it worked like a charm. Do you have a website? I would love to add a credit to you in the footer!

Comment: Thanks for the Kudos. If you'd like to add credit, you can use http://getwellgabby.org.

Comment: Did you make that website? It is very nice.

Comment: I am adding it to my site (which will be up in a bit). I will post a link up soon!

Answer (score 7):

You'll need an API for mapping visitors IP address to location ( [ipapi.co](https://ipapi.co/#api) ) and another one to get weather forecast for the location ( [openweathermap.org](http://openweathermap.org/api) ). The code below is for php (server side) :

```
# Part 1 (get latitude & longitude)
$ip = '1.2.3.4';
$api_1 = 'https://ipapi.co/' . $ip . '/latlong/';
$location = file_get_contents($api_1);
$point = explode(",", $location);

# Part 2 (get weather forecast)
$api_2 = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=' . $point[0] . '&lon=' . $point[1] . '&appid=API_KEY';
$weather = file_get_contents($api_2);
```

Comment: You can get extended forecast as well

`$api_3 = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?lat=' . $point[0] . '&lon=' . $point[1] . '&appid=' . $api_key;
$forecast = file_get_contents($api_3);`

Answer (score 1):

Using [ipinfo.io](http://ipinfo.io/) and [OpenWeatherMap](http://openweathermap.org/)

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.simpleopenweather.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.get("http://ipinfo.io", function (response) {
            $("#weather").attr('data-simpleopenweather-city', response.city).simpleopenweather({template: '<h2>'+'{{temperature}} '+'&deg;'+'C'+'<h2>', units: 'metric'});
        }, "jsonp");
    });
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div id="weather" class="simpleopenweather" data-simpleopenweather-city=""></div>
```

It will show something like 6.3 ºC

Answer (score 0):

```
***You can get data about the location with use third-party API. for example:http://ip-api.com/.**
You get your location weather data from OpenWeatherMap service using the ip-api. its help you to get visitor location weather.*



 var getIP = 'http://ip-api.com/json/';
    var openWeatherMap = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather'
    $.getJSON(getIP).done(function(location) {
        $.getJSON(openWeatherMap, {
            lat: location.lat,
            lon: location.lon,
            units: 'metric',
            APPID: 'Your-Openweather-Apikey'
        }).done(function(weather) {
          $('#weather').append(weather.main.temp);
            console.log(weather);
        })
    })
```

HTML:

```
<div id="weather"> </div>
```

It Shows your current weather temperature.